# Error ChainResolver

Tags: grails

I upgraded my Grails project from 2.1.1 to 2.2.2 and now I get this when I do run-app.

**| Error Error executing script RunApp: org/apache/ivy/plugins/resolver/ChainResolver (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)**

when I call run-app --stacktrace, it actually runs it but then stops running with the following error

INFO: No global web.xml found
May 31, 2013 11:55:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext

`Terminating process: Timeout: no new output for 60000 milliseconds`

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was becuase eclipse had saved old debug configuration for the previous grails version on this project. Go to Run>Debug Configuration>Grails Project and remove all the old configs!!!